# How does Barthes' ideas of Metalanguage differ from simple propositional logic?

Tags: semiotics, mathematical-logic

On the wikipedia for [post structuralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-structuralism#:%7E:text=Post%2Dstructuralism%20is%20a%20term,intellectual%20project%20that%20preceded%20it.),

> In Elements of Semiology (1967), Barthes advances the concept of the metalanguage, a systematized way of talking about concepts like meaning and grammar beyond the constraints of a traditional (first-order) language; in a metalanguage, symbols replace words and phrases. Insofar as one metalanguage is required for one explanation of the first-order language, another may be required, so metalanguages may actually replace first-order languages. Barthes exposes how this structuralist system is regressive; orders of language rely upon a metalanguage by which it is explained, and therefore deconstruction itself is in danger of becoming a metalanguage, thus exposing all languages and discourse to scrutiny. Barthes' other works contributed deconstructive theories about texts.

The idea of [symbolic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) existed already in 18th century (1700s), so what is new in Barthes ideas?

Note: As far as I understand this meta language idea is the same which underlies propositional logic/predicate logic. See [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/94770/49275) for an exaplanation given in a mathematical Logic book Stephen Kleene ( Student of Alonzo Church).

Comment: As far as Barthes' idea of metalanguage is that above: nothing new.

Comment: But the context: semiology, is not that of mathematical logic.

Comment: But metalanguage applies not only to propositional logic. Also to predicate logic, etc

Comment: I would have imagined all philosophers to have been educated with meta language/ propositional logic in that time.

Comment: There is a big distance from the idea of symbolic logic and the first order/meta-language distinction. Under the original conception, there was no separation between language about objects and language about language, they were taken as parts of the same language. Such a universal language is how logic was formalized by Russell in *Principia*. It is only after Godel's results and their reformulation by Tarski that the distinction was introduced to develop formal semantics while avoiding paradoxes of self-reference. It was still relatively novel in 1967, but it was Tarski's idea, not Barthes'.

Comment: I've browsed the Italian edition of Barthes' *Elements*: there are no references to mathematical or symbolic logic; neither to propositional logic.

Comment: The occurrences of "metalanguage" are very few and the definition introduced in para.IV.I is: "A metalanguage is a system whose plane of content is itself constituted by a signifying system […] it is a semiotics which treats of a semiotics.” Thus, the terms has no specific use in the book. Maybe, a more detailed reference to Barthes' works will help to give to the question some more interest.

Comment: A good starting point will be *Littérature et méta-langage* (1959) into: Roland Barthes, [Essais critiques (1964, Seuil)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Essais_critiques/7RV4CAAAQBAJ).